# Why do my browser devtools suddenly show sources as flat view instead of tree view?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

Up until about a week ago, in my browser devtools, my Javascript code looked like this: [image]

However, since a few days, it looks like a flat view:
[image]

More information which may be relevant:

- It happens in all up-to-date local browsers that I have, so in Chrome, Edge, and Firefox;
- This only happens with projects that I (re)build now. If I use (locally) build sources that are more than a week old, the sources look correct (so as a tree);
- I tried going back one version with Node (and the linked NPM), but that did not make any difference;
- I use an up-to-date Windows 11, and the latest VSCode;

What could be causing the different sources view? And how can I get the tree view back?